# React : How do you pass a parameter when making function call in a component property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a little lost with an error that states the parameter passed to a function is undefined. Here is how my code is laid out:

```
export const MainComponent = () => {
    const ToggleTipBtn = (id) => {

        //**Trying to add switch case based on 'id' but 'id' is undefined**
        switch(id){
             case 'someId':
             break;
         }
    

     }


    return(
      <Radio
         id='button1'
         label = 'someRadioButton'
      />
      <ToolTip
         id='helpTipBtn' //**Q: How can I pass the 'id' to the ToggleTipBtn? **
         toggle={ToggleTipBtn}  
    )
}
```

I am trying to pass the id property of Tooltip (this is a custom ToolTip component , not mui ToolTip) but I keep getting the error that 'id' is undefined. What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: where is that id coming from?

Comment: id is a property available in ToolTip. ToolTIp is a util library that I imported in.

Comment: What library are you using for the tooltip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If id prop is passed up to parent from the ToolTip toggle func then the syntax would be this

```
<Tooltip id='helpTipBtn' toggle={(id) => ToggleTipBtn(id)} />
```

Then inside of ToolTip child component when you call the function toggle you need to pass in id so like this

```
export const ToolTip = (id, toggle) => {
   const onToggle = () => {
     toggle(id);
   }


   return(
     <button onClick={onToggle}>Button</button>
   )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Will40. 
``
<Tooltip id='helpTipBtn' toggle={(id) => ToggleTipBtn(id)} />
```
still returns 'id' as undefined. I have added some more code for some clarification.